# Filtering with substrings and watching for change but no update

Tags: vue.js

I am working with substrings and watchers in vuejs. I have an issue. In my data model, I will end up having about 20 states that all have a code added to each of them. I filter out the code to just the first letters--that way I should be able too write some conditional render that will display the state name which would be indicative of the code. For instance if I have NY9830 OR NY83793, the substring cuts it down to just NY and I am trying to make the text update to New York. Its not updating and I added a watch to the v-model. I will have like 20 conditions for different states so, the easiest way to do this would be helpful.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#liveapp",

  data: function() {
    return {
      Office: 'NY006 '
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  watch: {
    stateValue: function() {
      if (this.office == "NY") {
        alert("display New York");
        this.stateValue = "New York";
      } else if (this.office == "LA") {
        alert("display Louisiana");
        this.stateValue = "Louisiana";
      }
    }
  },

  filters: {

    liveSubstr: function(string) {
      return string.substring(0, 2);
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="liveapp">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>

  <p v-model="stateValue">{{ Office | liveSubstr}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what values can change. Is it `office`? If so, how is it changeable?

Comment: office data changes--I just need that to update to the state name...so if the office data say "LA0003"--need the text to update to Louisiana. If office says "TX0894"--need text to say Texas

Comment: the office data will come in from rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, what I think you want is a filter that can transform an *office* code like *"NY9830"* into a full state name like *"New York"*.

You can back the filter with a map of state abbreviations to full-names. For example

```js
const states = new Map([
  ['NY', 'New York'],
  ['LA', 'Louisiana'],
  ['TX', 'Texas']
])

Vue.filter('state', value => {
  return states.get(value.substring(0, 2)) || 'Unknown'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ offices: [] }),
  created() {
    // simulate remote request
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.offices = ['NY9830', 'NY83793', 'LA7474', 'TX0894']
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="office in offices" :key="office">
      {{ office }} - {{ office | state }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```